# Roll 2 identical dice, let X, Y be the output of dice 1, 2 and $Z = X + Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the probability of:

1. $P(Z > 4|Y > 2)$
2. $P(Z > 4|X > Y > 2)$
3. $P(Y > 2|Z > 4)$

I already try something like so, list all possible variables:

1. $P(Z > 4|Y > 2) = \frac{|(X+Y>4) \cap (Y>2)|}{|Y > 2|} = \frac{23}{24}$
2. $P(Z > 4|X > Y > 2) = \frac{|(X+Y>4) \cap (X > Y > 2)|}{|X > Y > 2|} = \frac{6}{6}$
3. $P(Y > 2|Z > 4) = \frac{|(Y>2) \cap (X+Y>4)|}{|Z>4|} = \frac{23}{30}$

My question is, am I doing anything wrong? How can I simplify $|(X+Y>4) \cap (Y>2)|$, $|(X+Y>4) \cap (X > Y > 2)|$, $|(Y>2) \cap (X+Y>4)|$ ? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You put $|Y>2|$ in every denominator for some reason, but the final numbers look good to me.

Comment: oops that was my typo in denominator, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, am I doing anything wrong? How can I simplify $|(X+Y>4)∩(Y>2)|,$ ...

You have the correct numbers (despite the $P(Y>2)$ typo in the denominators).

The simplification process is as follows: Split the intersection into a union of disjoint intersections of independent sets; which becomes a sum of products of readily measured sets.

$\qquad\begin{align}\lvert (X+Y>4)\cap (Y>2)\rvert_{\tiny X{\times}Y} &=\lvert ((X+Y>4)\cap (Y=3))\cup((X+Y>4)\cap (Y > 3))\rvert_{\tiny X{\times}Y}\\&= \lvert (X>1)\cap (Y=3)\rvert_{\tiny X{\times}Y} +\lvert (1\leq X\leq 6)\cap(Y > 3)\rvert_{\tiny X{\times}Y}\\&=\lvert X>1\rvert_{\tiny X}\cdot\lvert Y=3\rvert_{\tiny Y}+\lvert 1\leq X\leq 6\rvert_{\tiny X}\cdot\lvert Y>3\rvert_{\tiny Y}\\&= 5\cdot 1+6\cdot 3 \\&=23\end{align}$

---

Also: because the sum will always exceed 4 when each of the terms exceeds 2.

$\quad \lvert(X+Y>4)\cap(X>Y>2)\rvert=\lvert X>Y>2\rvert$